# Negative smoke tests / defect seeding for validating PACT implementation

Tags: pact, pact-jvm, pact-java

We're implementing Pact framework for testing couple of microservices (Scala Backend & iOS-Android Frontend). So to test the Pact implementation itself, what sort of negative tests / defect seeding we can do to make sure that - the implemented Pact is catching what it supposed to catch?
i.e. once our Pact work’s complete we’re thinking to do defect seeding & see if errors like Query parameters, API response structure change , spelling changes in API paths etc are getting caught correctly by the PACT or not?
So on that line what other -ve tests & defect seeding, could we run on the implemented PACT framework? viz- Checklist for smoke test / exploratory tests to quickly test implemented PACT framework before its launched to live.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pact is not really designed for those types of tests. It can be done, but the extra variations in data often becomes an issue for providers [1].

There is a proposal to be able to "annotate" interactions by adding arbitrary labels for purposes such as this. If you'd like to add your thoughts to https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/issues/75 that would be helpful.

1. https://docs.pact.io/consumer#use-pact-for-isolated-unit-tests

Comment: thanks4the response. But if we've to do a smoke testing or exploratory testing of what we've implemented as part of PACT , then how do we validate (in controlled environment, non or semi-automated environment) that- its catching the bugs its supposed to catch?

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the question. You want to write tests, to validate that Pact tests are covering everything?

Comment: Yes. Basically to demonstrate on high level PACT framework is catching the bugs / issues which it is supposed to catch. Basically something similar to a induced failures / defect seeding.., which will then get detected by Pact in the Test/staging environment.